# File Input into Heap using inFile

Tags: c++, input, file-io, structure, heap

Hello I am currently having an issue with no print out where my loop stalls or is not functioning properly. I'm working with 3 files. Main.cpp, heap.h, and heapdata.txt.

This is all I have in main currently:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype> // for tolower
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "heap.h"
using namespace std;

int main () {

fileGet(0);

}
```

This is all I have in heap.h currently:

```
#ifndef HEAP_H
#define HEAP_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

struct member {
    string name;
    int id;
};

void fileGet(member heap[])
{
    char YN;
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    ifstream inFile;

    inFile.open("heapdata.txt",ios::in);

    // While loop to read the file
    while (inFile >> heap->id >> firstName >> lastName >> YN) {
        heap->name = firstName + " " + lastName;

    }
    cout << "test";

  inFile.close();
}

void reheapUp(member heap[], int size)
{
    int i = size-1; // current index
    int parent = (i-1)/2;
    while (i != 0 && heap[i].id > heap[parent].id)
    {
        int temp = heap[i].id;
        heap[i].id = heap[parent].id;
        heap[parent].id = temp;
        
        i = parent;
        parent = (i-1)/2;

    }
}

void reheapDown(int heap[], int size)
{
    int i = 0;
    int lc, rc, bigChild;
    lc = 2*i + 1;
    rc = 2*i + 1;
    while(lc < size) {
        if (rc < size) {
            if(heap[rc] > heap[lc])
                bigChild =rc;
            else
                bigChild = lc;
        }
        else
            bigChild = lc;

        if(heap[i] < heap[bigChild]) {
            int temp = heap[i];
            heap[i] = heap[bigChild];
            heap[bigChild] =temp;
        }
        else
            return;

        i = bigChild;
        lc = 2*i + 1;
        rc = 2*i + 2;      
    }
}

/*
void insertNode(int heap[], int& size, int key)
{
    heap[size] =key;
    size++;
    reheapUp(heap.id,size);
}
*/

int deleteNode(int heap[], int& size)
{
    int output = heap[0];
    heap[0] = heap[size-1];
    size--;
    reheapDown(heap, size);
    return output;
}

void printHeap(int heap[], int size)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << heap[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

#endif
```

This is the text inside of heapdata.txt:

```
41 Jona N
334 Vizility Y
169 Leaf Y
478 SoOn Y
962 Hqrdest Y
705 Sinatraa N
281 Corey N
961 Yawar N
995 Quinn Y
827 MSS Y
391 SVG Y
902 Saberlight N
292 CemaTheSlayer Y
421 Brokenblade Y
718 Spica N
447 Bjergsen Y
771 Zven Y
869 Smoothie Y
667 Wealthyman N
35 Snutz Y
```

This is the area of code I'm currently having issue (heap.h):

```
#define HEAP_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

struct member {
    string name;
    int id;
};

void fileGet(member heap[])
{
    char YN;
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    ifstream inFile;

    inFile.open("heapdata.txt",ios::in);

    // While loop to read the file
    while (inFile >> heap->id >> firstName >> lastName >> YN) {
        heap->name = firstName + " " + lastName;

    }
    cout << "test";

  inFile.close();
}
```

Code compiles but does not run test cout. Trying to put the first data entry into heap id, the second into firstName, the third into lastName, and the fourth into YN.

Comment: First thing remove that function definitions from header file (heap.h ) to a source file (heap.c)

Comment: sorry `.cpp` instead of `.c`

Comment: @sravs nothing wrong with defining functions in header files, why do you think it's causing a problem here?

Comment: `heap` is a null pointer so your code is probably crashing as soon as you try to write to it. Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: @Alan Birties, it does not cause problem here since its protected with `#ifndef HEAP_H` but that is not a good practice to define functions in header file

Comment: @sravs there is nothing wrong with defining functions in header files, in a lot of cases its advantageous or even required

Answer (score 1):

So the problem is that in this code

```
while (inFile >> heap->id >> firstName >> lastName >> YN)
```

`heap` is a null pointer, and so `heap->id` crashes your program.

You can see that `heap` is a null pointer is you look where you call `fileGet` in `main`.

```
int main () {

fileGet(0);

}
```

As you can see `0` (which is another way of writing the null pointer in C++) is passed to `fileGet`, so `heap` in `fileGet` is a null pointer.

Now that's the problem, but the solution is less clear as the code is a little bit confused. It looks like you are trying to read values from the file into an array. If that is the case then you need to pass the array to `fileGet` instead of a null pointer.

The simplest fix (not necessarily the best) would be something like this

```
int main () {
    member array[100];  // declare the array
    fileGet(array);     // pass it to the fileGet function
}
```

I decalred the array to be size 100 in the hope that is big enough for any file you are trying to read. As I said this isn't the best solution, but I think something simple to help you progress is what is needed.

BTW some other problems I notice. Look at your file, **three** items on each line. Look at the line that reads the file `inFile >> heap->id >> firstName >> lastName >> YN`, it reads **four** items. Obviously that isn't right. You need to pay attention to these kind of details.

Also, maybe this is just a work in progress, but nothing in the code here reads values into member::name (only member::id), and nothing reads values into an *array*. If you want to read values into an array you need an index variable and the `[]` operator, something like `inFile >> heap[i].id >> ...`. You did this correctly in your `printHeap` function, you need something similar in your `fileGet` function.

Answer (score -1):

How do you expect this to work when you pass zero `fileGet(0);`
pass a proper address by declaring a structure of

```
struct member {
    string name;
    int id;
};
struct member  M1; 
fileGet(M1); // add this in main
```

and use `return M1;` in `fileGet()` at the end, since you are passing by value, finally correct your `while` loop , instead do the read/write part inside

```
while(condition)
{
  // code here
}
```

Comment: `finally correct your while loop , instead do the read/write part inside`, nope, putting the reads inside the while loop condition is not incorrect, its a good way to ensure the reads have suceeded

Comment: `passing by value` this is also incorrect, the argument in the code is an array not a value